# iOS XMPP client disconnects after some time

Tags: ios, chat, openfire, xmppframework

Am using open fire server and iOS xmpp client with Robbie Hanson's framework. My clients runs fine in background, as i have set the voip flag and everything. But after few hours around 15-20, it automatically gets disconnected. Am not sure why it's happening and why it is taking such long duration. I am not sending any messages or receiving any. The ping interval is 360 secs to which my client responds with an error, which is acceptable form of response to remain connected to the server. Anyone got the same issue ?

Openfire server: 3.8.1
iOS version: 6.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the setting "Do Not disconnect clients that are idle" available in Server Settings> Client Connections in Openfire server?

Comment: Well if i do that, then if the client loses network connectivity, he will never be shown offline as the he will always be connected to the server.

Comment: Okay, an update: The app wasn't crashing, but the OS killed it for some reason when i opened gmail on safari, even yahoo mail. I have no clue why this is happening. The device which i used is a fourth generation iPod.